# Error while installing TF Object Detection API

Tags: python, linux, tensorflow

I am trying to install Tensorflow Object Detection API, following [those instructions](https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#tf-models-install). Everything goes well till the moment I have to run python -m pip install within the models/research directory. It starts collecting and installing the various packages, but when it reaches the installation of tf-models-official, it produces the following error :

```
ERROR: Cannot install object-detection because these package versions have conflicting dependencies.

The conflict is caused by:
    tf-models-official 2.7.0 depends on tensorflow-addons
    tf-models-official 2.6.1 depends on tensorflow-addons
    tf-models-official 2.6.0 depends on tensorflow-addons
    tf-models-official 2.5.1 depends on tensorflow-addons

To fix this you could try to:
1. loosen the range of package versions you've specified
2. remove package versions to allow pip attempt to solve the dependency conflict
```

I did up a bit of digging online, but didn't manage to find anything in the Github repo of tensorflow or other websites. I am using Tensorflow 2.7.0 and Python 3.9.2, on a Linux 64-bit OS. I also tried with Python 3.7.12 but the same error persisted, while manual installation of tensorflow-addons using pip install indicates that no matching distribution was found.

Answer (score -1):

python-3.10.2-amd64: error

python-3.9.10-amd64: ok

python-3.9.2-amd64: ok

python-3.8.10-amd64: ok

---

`python -m pip install --use-feature=2020-resolver tensorflow`

'--use-feature=2020-resolver' could be a good solution.

---

Did you use "tensorflow==2.5.0"?

Don't use specific version like "==2.5.0".

---

UPDATE

See https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow/#history

tensorflow 2.8.0 (Feb 3, 2022)

I installed tf 2.7.0 and then when I tried to install object detection, tf was reinstalled into tf 2.8.0. So I thought it is weird but I didn't know that tf 2.8.0 doesn't exist yet when you tried to install object detection.

If you try again, tf will be reinstalled automatically into 2.8.0.

Comment: Did you mean error in python-3.9.2?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @DrSpill python-3.9.2 is no error.